# g++ much slower on multiple files vs. monolithic single file using Google mock

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm having a problem that appears to be g++ related. Basically, g++ takes substantially more time to compile a program when it is split into multiple files versus a single monolithic file. In fact, if you cat the individual files together and compile that, it runs much faster than if you list the individual files on the g++ command line. For example, with nine files, it takes 1 minute, 39 seconds to compile; when I cat them together it only takes 13 seconds to compile. I've tried using `strace` but it just gets stuck in `cc1plus`; when I use the `-f` option I still can't sort out what's causing the problem.

I've isolated the problem. Here is how to reproduce it. I wrote a very simple program, like so:

```
void func_01(int i) 
{
  int j;
  volatile int *jp;

  jp = &j;

   for (; i; i--) ++*jp;
}

void call_01(void)
{
  func_01(10000);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  call_01();
}
```

Then I replicated it, removing main and substituting increasing numbers, 999 times. Then I built:

```
% time g++ -c test*.cpp

real    0m18.919s
user    0m10.208s
sys     0m5.595s
% cat test*.cpp > mon.cpp
% time g++ -c mon.cpp  

real    0m0.824s
user    0m0.776s
sys     0m0.040s
```

Because I intend to scale to hundreds of files much more complex than this, it's important to get the build time down. Can anyone help explain why this is happening, or offer a less gross workaround? I think it has in part to do with the preprocessor and the savings caused by include guards, because if I include even one file, the time difference is dramatically increased (a factor of five in one case) but it still remains, without includes, a factor of twenty faster to go with the monolithic file.

The version of g++ is 4.4.2, but I checked the latest version, 8.2.0, and it exists there as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt you will have an answer here. Compilation times for C++ code (especially when optimizations are turned on, which you do not have) are known to be high, and people tend to learn to live with it.

Comment: Just a educated guess: In the large file the compiler can see that nothing is used except for `call_01()` and `func_01(int i) ` so it can optimize out all of the other code.  In the multi file approach it can't.  So it has to generate code for all of that and then leave it to the linker to decide what makes it into the binary.

Comment: @NathanOliver wouldn't apply to the minimal example there, should be exactly the same optimizations allowed...

Comment: Have you tried to use precompiled-headers ? i.e. something like: `$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(DEFINES) -c src/stdafx.hpp -o $(OBJ)/stdafx.hpp.gch` and `$(OBJ)/%.o: src/%.cpp
 $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(DEFINES) -iquoteobj$(OBJ)/stdafx.hpp.gch -c $< -o $@`  in your make file. An example [make file](https://github.com/incoder1/IO/blob/master/Makefile-unix-shared)

Comment: @VictorGubin Ah! I was wondering about whether g++ offered that feature but I never followed through on checking. Will look into that, thank you!

Comment: Don't forget that with many small files you can compile them in parallel.

Comment: @eewanco @Anty  with `make -j <N>` where N is number of parallel processes. CPU cores (number of threads in case of hyperthreading) is good choose for this parameter, for example `make -j 8`. But in case of the recompiled headers - it must be compiled very first, before any another files, so `make -j <N>` can be incompatible with this option, since no any ordering guaranty. Such build also may stress all your system to 100% CPU usage to long period of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different effects:

1. Compiler invocation overhead: Compilers are complicated executables and sometimes they are even split into a frontend and a backend executable and the frontend spawns the backend for each individual source file, even when all source files are passed to the same compiler invocation of the frontend. Gcc and llvm do that for example.

   - Specify `g++ -v` to see these redundant compiler invokations. This answers your main question I think of why this happens even without header files.
2. Overhead due to parsing and compiling the same header files over and over again from scratch. In real-world examples this header overhead will be much more significant than the compiler invocation itself.

> because if I include even one file, the time difference is dramatically increased (a factor of five in one case)

Yes! And this could also be well 1000 times slower instead of 5 times. With template intensive code the compiler needs to do a lot, at compile time.

The slowdown when splitting across many source files is hitting you especially for C++ code because C++ is *header intensive*. All your source `*.cpp` are compiled separately and all the headers they include are included redundantly for each individual source file.

Now if you cat all the source files together all the headers are, as you said, parsed only once because of the include guards. Since the compiler spends a great proportion of its time parsing and compiling the headers this is very significant, especially with template heavy code (e.g. using STL is enough).

The number of source files for hand-written C++ source code and also for generated C++ source code is a tradeoff between:

1. My full rebuild time is fast, but my incremental build time is slow.

   - This is the case when you have only one source file (meaning *.cpp files) or very little source files.
2. My full build time is slow, but my incremental build time is fast.

   - This is the case when you have lots of small source files (meaning *.cpp files).

(In any case, the number of header files does not matter much (except when you always pull in too much redundant stuff. This is about the number of compiler invocations which is the number of *.cpp or *.o files.)

For 1. the full compilation time from scratch is short since the compiler sees all the headers only once, which is significant in C++ and especially with template based header-only (or header intensive) libraries like STL or boost.

For 2. the individual compilation time is fast since only very few code in the *.cpp file is to be compiled when just a single of hundreds of files changed.

It strongly depends on your use case.

In case you generate the C++ code you should add an option to your generator to allow the user to choose which way to go with this tradeoff.

Comment: ***the number of header files does not matter much*** I have seen this to be a big impact on compile times if there are way too many paths in the include paths specified to the compiler.

Comment: OP's example have no header files.

Comment: @SergeyA That is true, but my original problem does involve header files. It occurred to me last night that maybe I got into the weeds trying to isolate an example -- with 1,000 files, the file access overhead alone could very possibly explain the time difference. And I see Bo R concluded this as well in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe in this case the majority of the overhead comes from opening and closing files. In both cases, you have one process doing the job.

I did a comparison with the `cat` program dumping the results to /dev/null. For `cat test_*.cpp >/dev/null` it took ~0.008s and for `cat mon.cpp >/dev/null` ~0.001s. That almost a 10 times difference for 999 files. Add to this that the compiler also has to set up some internal management for each file that it compiles that's only done once for the big monolithic case.

But as others have answered setting up the build in a build system like make or ninja, the difference becomes apparent when touching just *one* file of many compared to the mono-file. Rebuilding with ninja took `1.196s` for the mono case but only `0.233s` for the 999 file case.

NB: No explicit header files involved in these numbers.

Comment: Probably the real overhead is 1 compiler process vs. spinning 999 compiler processes, and the overhead of compiling each file.

Comment: @valiano None of initial examples inolved compiling them all in concurrently. And neither did I. I did try with ninja and make and ran with a -j6 flag on my 4-core machine thou.

Comment: @BoR yeah I came to the same conclusion last night, I think my example is a red herring. The real culprit is the header file re-processing overhead. I've never heard of ninja; do you have a good resource handy for that? Googling for "ninja" probably won't help LOL.

Comment: @eewanco Try https://ninja-build.org/ but you'll likley want to generate its file with CMake. So installing on a linux system you just look for ninja-build.